# Unproject MouseCoords ( OpenGL / OpenTK ).

Tags: c#, opengl, mouse, opentk

Hey I am trying to convert 2d mouse coords to a 3d direction vector to world space. The problem is that the direction vector of the ray is only fully working if the camera is not turning in Y-axis. For example: Camera looking down. Y is -0.999 thats perfect, but now I turn the camera 90° in Y-axis and the result is that X is now -0.999 and Y very small ( but still looking down ). The only direction thats working is Z.

This is the code for getting the mouse ray.

```
        public Vector3 get3DMouseCoords(int mousex, int mousey)
    {
        Vector2 normalizedCoords = getNormalizedMouseCoords(mousex, mousey);
        Vector4 clipCoords = new Vector4(normalizedCoords.X, normalizedCoords.Y, -1f, 1f);
        Vector4 eyeRay = getEyeRay(clipCoords);
        return getWorldRay(eyeRay);
    } 

    private Vector3 getWorldRay(Vector4 eyeRay)
    {
        Matrix4 invertertedView = Matrix4.Invert(Camera.Transformation);
        Vector3 worldRay = Vector4.Transform(invertertedView, eyeRay).Xyz;
        return worldRay.Normalized();
    }

    private Vector4 getEyeRay(Vector4 clipCoords)
    {
        Matrix4 invertertedProj = Matrix4.Invert(Camera.PerspectiveProjection);
        Vector4 eyeRay = Vector4.Transform(invertertedProj, clipCoords);
        return new Vector4(eyeRay.X, eyeRay.Y, -1f, 0f);
    }

    private Vector2 getNormalizedMouseCoords(int mousex, int mousey)
    {
        float x = 2.0f * mousex / (float)screenWidth - 1;
        float y = -(2.0f * mousey / (float)screenHeight - 1);
        return new Vector2(x, y);
    }
```

This is the view matrix code:

```
                    Vector3 lookat = new Vector3();

                lookat.X = (float)(Math.Sin((float)orientation.X) * Math.Cos((float)orientation.Y));
                lookat.Y = (float)Math.Sin((float)orientation.Y);
                lookat.Z = (float)(Math.Cos((float)orientation.X) * Math.Cos((float)orientation.Y));

                view = Matrix4.LookAt(Position, Position + lookat, Vector3.UnitY);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have two questions, which may help you. 1: why are you discarding eyeRay.Z when returning getEyeRay? EDIT: Nevermind number 2, you and I do that differently but it's not wrong.

Comment: I finally fixed it.  Vector4.Transform(invertertedView, eyeRay).Xyz; was not what I needed. Vector4 vec = (invertedView*eyeRay).Xyz. Was giving the right results. But I dont know why transform wasnt working...

Comment: Weird, glad you fixed it! Please post your answer and accept it, so people know the issue is resolved.